# Apollo GraphQL: Can One Query Support Lookup Different Lookup Fields?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollostack

I've got a working query that looks like this:

```
const GETONEASSOCIATE_QUERY = gql`
query getOneAssociate($_id: String!) {
  getOneAssociate(_id: $_id) {
    _id
    first_name
    last_name
    city
    state
    userIDinRelatedTable
  }
} `;
```

Now I'd like to be able to look up an associate by `userIDinRelatedTable`. Do I have to write a whole new graphQL query, or, is there a way to set up a query so that I can specify what fields to be used for the lookup -- something like:

`enter code here`query getOneAssociate($_args: args) {

Thanks in advance to all for any thoughts/advice/info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing in your scheme you have a userIDinRelatedTable field on Associate which resolves to RelatedTable.

So to get the fields returned in your query you can

```
const GETONEASSOCIATE_QUERY = gql`
  query getOneAssociate($_id: String!) {
    getOneAssociate(_id: $_id) {
    _id
    first_name
    last_name
    city
    state
    userIDinRelatedTable {
      id
      field1
      field2
    }
  }
} `;
```